# NSString class types

Tags: objective-c

Is it possible to get the name of a class into a string like this:

```
NSString *kls = (NSString *)[self.name class];
NSLog(@"%@", [kls isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] ? @"YES" : @"NO");
```

I can do: `NSString *kls = [[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@", [self.name class]]autorelease];`

but that seems a bit long-winded to me. 
It's not for any task in particular, I'm just trying to learn more about the language as I go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the Mac, provided your object inherits from the `NSObject` *class* rather than just implementing the `NSObject` *protocol* (the latter situation seems sort of unlikely), you should be able to call:

```
NSString* str = [anObject className];
```

`className` is defined in connection with Mac scripting support, so it is not available on the iOS version of `NSObject`. In that case, you can probably do something like this:

```
NSString* str = [[anObject class] description];
```

(I have only actually tried this on a Mac, though, so it's possible it may not work correctly on an iOS device.)

Comment: Don't use the -description method in production code.  For debugging? Sure.  Use `NSStringFromClass()`.

Comment: @bbum I'm not about to argue with the mighty bbum, but I am curious: do you mean that -description may legitimately fail or produce strange results at runtime? And that's expected? It seems kind of perverse if so.

Comment: Oh, hell, please.. argue with me if I'm wrong. :)  `-description` is defined to be, more or less, a "runtime description of the object".  It will sometimes -- more rarely for some objects than others -- change over time to provide a better runtime description.  `NSStringFromClass()` and `NSClassFromString()` are explicitly designed to be bidirectional conversion conduit for classes / class names.

Answer (score 1):

NSString* classNameStr = [NSStringFromClass](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSStringFromClass)( [anObject class] );